# Download DB in Admin panel

Tags: database

How to download my drupal site DB in my Drupal 7? I want to know is there any options are there in download db in admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to used something like phpMyAdmin because Backup and Migrate can not be restored from the server level.And you can have some performances issues.